# SimpleDateFormat not producing expected output

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have used JCalender to get the date. It returned the date like this

```
Thu Mar 01 18:35:53 PST 2012
```

But what I need is this format.

```
01/03/2012
```

I have tried  the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat MydateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            FromDate.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener(
new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        if ("date".equals(e.getPropertyName())) {
            System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()
                + ": -->" + (Date) e.getNewValue());
                try {
                    fdate = MydateFormat.parse(e.getNewValue().toString());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, fdate);
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DashboardChart.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

        }       
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you were asking for was a new `Date` object based on the current one.  Try this:

```
package test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestDateFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat MydateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        String fdate = MydateFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(date + " \tFORMATTED: " + fdate);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fdate);
    }
}
```

### E.G. Output

```
Sat Mar 24 23:40:09 EST 2012    FORMATTED: 24/03/2012
```